# Validating the mathematical or arithmetic expression from a input string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I need a solution for validating a mathematical or arithmetic expression from a form input using JavaScript or TypeScript. The validator should allow arithmetic operator like `()`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `avg()`, `min()`, `max()`.

I am looking for a validator, not the math evaluator. For example, the input can be 
`((x+y-z)+(min(min(x,y),z)+avg(x,y))`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Here we expect you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please attempt something, then update your question to show a **specific** problem you're having in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: As Obsidian Age said, you should post a minimal, complete and verifiable example and try to solve it yourself (and post what you've tried). In short, you're going to just have to write your own parser which will read the values and handle them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [expression-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expression-eval).  To install run the following command:

```
npm install expression-eval
```

Then to use it use

```
const expr = require('expression-eval');
const result = expr.parse('((x+y-z)+(min(min(x,y),z)+avg(x,y))')

// This will give an error like
// Error: Unclosed ( at character 35
//     at throwError (/home/simon/node_modules/jsep/build/jsep.js:38:16)
//     at gobbleGroup (/home/simon/node_modules/jsep/build/jsep.js:521:7)
//     at gobbleVariable (/home/simon/node_modules/jsep/build/jsep.js:465:14)
//     at gobbleToken (/home/simon/node_modules/jsep/build/jsep.js:295:15)
//     at gobbleBinaryExpression (/home/simon/node_modules/jsep/build/jsep.js:203:13)
//     at gobbleExpression (/home/simon/node_modules/jsep/build/jsep.js:142:17)
//     at Object.jsep [as parse] (/home/simon/node_modules/jsep/build/jsep.js:547:17)
```

However, adding a bracket to the end solves the issue:

```
const result = expr.parse('((x+y-z)+(min(min(x,y),z)+avg(x,y)))')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not looking for a parser.I want to validate the syntax of the string expression in javascript.

Comment: You will have to be more clear with your question.  This parser will validate the syntax, if validation fails, then you will get an error message.  If validation is a success then you get an AST (abstract syntax tree).

Answer (score 0):

Check this plugin, [exp.js](https://exp.js.org), it validates and runs the arithmetic expression with variables. You define your own functions with different signature.